# String concatenation performance

Tags: python, string-concatenation

Right now I use a list to store altered string and return a string with .join()

```
def applyCoder(text, coder):
    l = []
    for i in text:
        if i in coder:
            l.append(coder[i])
        else:
            l.append(i)
    return ''.join(l)

# example output, shifts all letters by 3 in a string
# print applyCoder("Hello, world!", buildCoder(3))
# buildCoder(3) returns dictionary, e.g. {'A': 'D', ...}
# >>> Khoor, zruog!
```

Is there a faster method to change and return a string?

Comment: Fix your `return` statement

Answer (score 4):

This should be as fast as possible:

```
''.join([coder[i] if i in coder else i for i in text])
```

List comprehensions are much more optimized in Python compared to `for` loops which bear great overhead. I've passed a list comprehension as opposed to a generator in `''.join` because it must know the length of it's input in advance before joining. If you give it a generator it has to make that into a list anyway (which is a bit slower).

Actually you can simplify this even further, <s>which *should* be even faster</s>
(**this actually performs slower than the above method due to the method call**)

```
''.join([coder.get(i,i) for i in text])
```

Timings:

```
def applyCoder(text, coder):
    L = []
    for i in text:
        if i in coder:
            L.append(coder[i])
        else:
            L.append(i)
    return ''.join(L)

def list_comp(text, coder):
    return ''.join([coder[i] if i in coder else i for i in text])

def list_comp2(text, coder):
    return ''.join([coder.get(i,i) for i in text])

from timeit import timeit
from string import ascii_letters
d = dict(zip(ascii_letters, ascii_letters[3:] + ascii_letters[-3:]))


print timeit(stmt='applyCoder("Hello, world!", d)',
             setup='from __main__ import applyCoder, d;')

print timeit(stmt='list_comp("Hello, world!", d)',
             setup='from __main__ import list_comp, d;')    

print timeit(stmt='list_comp2("Hello, world!", d)',
             setup='from __main__ import list_comp2, d;')

print timeit(stmt='applyCoder("Hello, world!"*10, d)',
             setup='from __main__ import applyCoder, d;')

print timeit(stmt='list_comp("Hello, world!"*10, d)',
             setup='from __main__ import list_comp, d;')


print timeit(stmt='list_comp2("Hello, world!"*10, d)',
             setup='from __main__ import list_comp2, d;')
```

Results:

```
''' Test 1 '''
5.0159105417    # applyCoder
3.41502481461   # listcomp1
4.76796932292   # listcomp2

''' Test 2 '''
34.9718502631   # applyCoder
22.0451702661   # listcomp1
34.1682597928   # listcomp2
```

It appears that the method call to `coder.get` completely negates the advantages of the list comprehension. I did predict it might be slower than `listcomp1` because of this but I didn't think it would have this much of an impact. Anyway the list comprehension still wins.

**Update:**
If you modify `list_comp2` like so:

```
def list_comp2(text, coder):
    coder_get = coder.get
    return ''.join([coder_get(i,i) for i in text])
```

The times improve drastically:

from `4.76796932292` (1st test) -> `3.95217394948`

and `34.1682597928` (2nd test) -> `27.1162974624`

Comment: Average: 0.00015 vs 0.00011(yours) with 10,000 calls.

Comment: @user2144553 those must be tiny inputs, (I'm assuming those are seconds), can you try it on larger ones? Also if you could tell me the timings of both of mine EDIT: I'll try some timings as well

Comment: I used two and half average sentence long string. Here is my setup: http://pastie.org/7641446

Comment: @user2144553 Doing some timings now, it appears my first method is much faster than yours but the second one is slow, will update shortly

Comment: @user2144553 Updated: I did my tests  using `timeit` which is much more accurate

Comment: @jamylak, never used timeit -- `22.0451702661` for `list_comp` with helloworld string is not in seconds?

Comment: @user2144553 yes it's *the time it takes to execute the main statement a number of times, measured in seconds as a float*, in this case it's 1,000,000 times by default